# Delete last characters before delimiter

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, cut

### The Input file content is like:

```
header;header;header;header
2018/06/04;141000;bla;bla
```

### Desired Output:

```
header;header;header;header
2018/06/04;1410;bla;bla
```

I have the command below with **sed**

```
sed -i 's/.//16' $inputFile
```

But deletes my header like:

```
header;hder;header;header
2018/06/04;1410;bla;bla
```

To avoid that I tried to do:

```
tail -n +2 | sed -i 's/.//16' $inputFile
```

But is not working. Thanks in advance

Comment: `sed -i -- '1!s/.//16' "$inputFile"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' 'NR > 1 { sub("..$", "", $2) }; 1' <"$inputFile"
```

This would modify the second `;`-delimited field on every line of input except from the first, by removing the last two characters from it.

The trailing `1` causes every line to be outputted (it may be replaced by `{ print }`).

You would redirect the output of this to a new file which you later could replace the original with.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas As usual, thanks. I'll learn _and_ remember, one day.

Answer (score 1):

If two characters are to be removed before the second delimiter (and assuming like in your sample that there are always at least two characters before each of the first two delimiters), use:

```
sed -i -- '1!s/..;/;/2' "$inputFile"
```

The `1!` avoids changing the header (first) line.
The rest removes two characters just before the delimiter `;`.